# Java retrieving a custom key object from a map

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

This may not be the best data structure, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this:
I have a set of tools, each with a unique Id and a bunch or attributes.  Each tool also has a collection of chambers which contain attributes.
I was hoping to use the tool as the key to a HashMap and the List of Chambers as the value.
After I get back all of the chamber information from the database, I want to get the key object (tool)  by toolId so that I can add each chamber to its appropriate tool.  I over-rode the equals method and hash method to use the toolId.

**Other than bringing back all the keys and iterating over them to see if they equal the toolId, is there some way to get the key object**

Here is my code so far:

```
Public class ToolBean {

    Private String toolId;
    Private String toolName;
    Private String toolOwner;

    Public ToolBean(String toolId){
        this.toolId = toolId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ToolBean other = (ToolBean) obj;
        if (toolId == null) {
            if (other.toolId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!toolId.equals(other.toolId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((toolId == null) ? 0 : toolId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

The structure I am creating will look like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<ToolBean, LinkedHashMap<String, ChamberBean>> toolWithChamberMap =  new LinkedHashMap<ToolBean, LinkedHashMap<String, ChamberBean>>();
```

I know that I can create a structure with the ToolBean having an LinkedHashMap  of Chambers (LinkedHashMap ) then open the tool, add the new chamber to the map, the put the tool back in the original map.  I was wondering if there was a way to skip that step.

Thanks,
Brita

Comment: Just create a second HashMap with Key=toolid and Value=tool.

Comment: This looks like enough code to allow you to use your ToolBean class with hash maps. The code looks pretty good to me, assuming that you always consider two objects identical if they have the same tool id.

Comment: So what's your question anyway? Will the code work? I think it will. Have you tried it? What happened? DaoWen's answer is a good one, but I don't think you need to do it. With the code you've added to ToolBean, ToolBean objects can reasonably acts as keys in a hash map.

Comment: So the question is: I have a chamber object from the data base and it needs to be added to the tool with toolId = 'aaa'
How do I get/add the value to the key?  Will getKey('aaa') work or do I need to get the object?

Comment: This may not be clear but the ToolObject with toolId 'aaa' already has chamber 'one' and I need to add chamber 'two' to the chamber map.  Can (How Can) I do this using the ToolObject as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
class ToolBean { 
    // as described in OP
}

class Chamber {
    // some opaque class
}
```

What you seem to be asking for is this:

```
// Master map of ToolBean to map of Chamber objects
Map<ToolBean, Map<String, Chamber>> toolBeanToChamberMap = 
    new LinkedHashMap<ToolBean,Map<String,Chamber>>();

// A tool bean and a chamber
ToolBean tb1 = new ToolBean(...);
Chamber  ch1 = new Chamber(...);

// Create a map that will contain Chambers and their String keys
Map<String,Chamber> chMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Chamber>();

// Put the Chamber into this map
chMap.put("one",ch1);

// Put the map of Chambers into the master map, keyed off the ToolBean
toolBeanToChamberMap.put(tb1, chMap);

// sometime later ...

ToolBean tb2 = ... // may be the same as tb1

// A new Chamber to be added to the data structure
Chamber ch2 = new Chamber(...);

// First find the Chamber map in the master map, matching the ToolBean of interest
Map<String,Chamber> temp = toolBeanToChamberMap.get(tb2);

// 'temp' is a reference to the submap - if it's null, this ToolBean wasn't in the master map yet
if (temp == null) {
    // So create a new empty submap
    temp = new LinkedHashMap<String,Chamber>();
    // Add it to the master map
    toolBeanToChamberMap.put(tb2,temp);
}
// At this point 'temp' is either the pre-existing submap or the one we just added
temp.put("two",ch2);
```

*However*, unless you have a really good reason for doing things this way, I'd suggest the following:

```
public class ToolBean {
    some attributes...
    Map<String, Chamber> chamberMap = new LinkedHashmap<String,Chamber>();
    ...
    public void addChamber(String name, Chamber c) {
        // similar logic as above
    }
    public Chamber getChamber(String name) {
        return chamberMap.get(name);
    }
}

Set<ToolBean> toolBeans = new HashSet<ToolBean>();

ToolBean tb1 = new ToolBean();
tb1.addChamber("one", new Chamber(...));
tb1.addChamber("two", new Chamber(...));
toolBeans.add(tb1);
```

In other words, hide all the complexity of the map of chambers inside the `ToolBean` class.

Handling of duplicate Chamber values, and null values, left as an exercise.

Comment: Once I create the first ToolBean and put it in the map,  how do I get and add back the map of chambers.

If my first key (ToolBean) is a tool with toolId=’aaa’ and the chamber map has chamber ‘one’ and I want to add chamber ‘two’.
Would it look like 
     chamberMap = toolWithChamberMap(‘aaa’)  
     chamberMap.put(‘one’, chamber)  ?

I know I can do it like Nikita suggests, but I am trying to see if I can ToolBean as the key.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't clear that you want to look up `ToolBean` instances using chamber maps as the key.  That is a different problem altogether and my answer does not apply.  What is the definition of a `Chamber` object? What does `toolWithChamberMap("aaa")` return? How does `"aaa"` refer to a `Chamber` object? You haven't really provided enough information.

Comment: I am sorry to be so bad at explaining things.
1st object Key1 = ToolBean { toolId = ‘tool1’; toolName = ‘name1’; toolData=’someData”;}
                 Value1 = chamberMap1 {‘one’, chamber1}

I need to modify chamberMap1 in order to add chamber ‘two’.  How do I do that?
/n can I use the tooId and the equals function, or do I need to create the entire object to get the chamber map?

Comment: Jim,
Exactly perfect.  Wonderfully well structured answer, just what I needed to know.  I wish I had enough points to upvote it.  Thanks.  Brita

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd create 2 maps: ToolId -> ToolBean and ToolId -> Chambers. It similar to your approach but I don't like ToolBean being key in the map. I don't see much benefits of ToolBean as keys and also it compilcates code because you need to override equals and hashcode methods that ignore name and owner.

Second way is to embed chambers to ToolBean itself.

Third way that uses your code is this: having ToolId you can create instance of ToolBean using this id and use it as key to retrieve map of chambers. Personally it feels like hack to me.